# Windows vbs script

Tags: windows, vbscript, startup

I'm trying to make a vbs script to set an application to run on windows startup, but it seems not to work...
here's the code:

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
pathe = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
start()
function start()
x = fs.CopyFile("hello.bat", Path & "\", True)
end function
wscript.echo(Path)
```

if you know any other method to set a file to run on startup it is good

Comment: Replace `pathe` with `path`. Also remove the lines `function start()` and `end function`.

Comment: Why would you be copying a batch file to the start-up directory, _in order to make it run on every startup_, but then invoking that copy process by running a vbscript on every startup. The idea is ill thought out, or intended malicious behavior. Why not just start the batch file in its current location, as a scheduled task, and exclude the vbscript completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just a one liner can do this:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(7).CopyHere "hello.bat", 4 + 16 + 1024 : Wscript.Echo "hello.bat"
```